# How to pass data from API using useContext?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass some data through useContext() that I'm getting from a Contentful API but I can't figure out how. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

First, I get the data and save it in a state:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

function getProducts() {
   Client.getEntries("products")
      .then((entry) => {
         entry.items.map((item) => {
            setProducts(products.push(item));
      });
   })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

useEffect(() => {
   getProducts();
}, []);
```

Then I pass the state to the Provider:

```
<ProductContext.Provider value={{ products }}>
   //children
</ProductContext.Provider>
```

When I log 'products' inside the getProducts() function, I get an array with a bunch of objects, but when I try to map it somewhere else in my app, I get a products.map is not a function.

```
import { ProductContext } from "../../../Context";

export default function ProductList() {
  const { products } = useContext(ProductContext);

  return (
    <Container>
      {products.map(product => {
        //do something
      })}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: please show us how u are using it..?

Comment: You are setting state in loop. Is that intentional ? *entry.items.map((item) => {
            setProducts(products.push(item));
      });*

Comment: should I just setProducts(entry.items)? I tried and it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

```
.then((entry) => {
         entry.items.map((item) => {
            setProducts(products.push(item));
      });
```

could be simplified to

```
.then((entry) => setProducts(entry.items));
```

Maybe that's not the cause, but could be that the multiple calls to `setProducts()` cause some delay (set of state is asynchronous)